# Python changing modifying via imported function

Tags: python, django-middleware, django-settings

I am trying to create a function, that when imported and then called, it will check and modify a tuple. I would like to be able to call this multiple times. However, I just have the function return the new variable, because I can not figure out a way to change the variable in place.

Here is my examples with two files, how I would like it to work:

```
**modifier.py**
import variable

def function(new_string):
    if new_string not in variable.tuple:
        variable.tuple = new_string, + variable.tuple

**variable.py**
import modifier

tuple = ('one','two',)

modifier.function('add this')

modifier.function('now this')

#--> tuple should now equal ('now this', 'add this', 'one', 'two',)
```

However right now I have to do this:

```
**modifier.py**    
def function(tuple_old, new_string):
    if new_string not in tuple_old:
        return new_string, + tuple_old

**variable.py**
import modifier

tuple = ('one','two',)

tuple = modifier.function(tuple, 'add this')

tuple = modifier.function(tuple, 'now this')

#--> tuple now equals ('now this', 'add this', 'one', 'two',)
```

This is a lot messier. First off, I have to pass in the old tuple value and get a returned value, instead of replacing the tuple directly. It works, but its not DRY and I know there must be a way to make this cleaner.

---

I can't use lists, because this is actually a function to update my middleware on my django settings file. Also I don't *have* to have the function on a different file, but I also think it should be possible.

Comment: Have you *tried* the code in the first block?

Comment: You have a cyclic import

Comment: You have a tuple called `tuple` shadowing the builtin

Comment: @wim: Cyclic imports can look wrong, yet can work fine.

Comment: @win I can however replace a tuple with a new tuple that is the combination of two old tuples.

Comment: @wim I also just created the variable for show here, I am using specific ones in my application

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes I have tried it. It does not work because when it checks the variable file for occurrences in the tuple, it does not import the new variable file. Just the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong about what you're doing right now (last code block), it's clear. If I see something like:

```
tuple = # something ...
```

I know that tuple is changed (probably it's just a name you used for the example, but don't call your variable "tuple").

But if I see this (what you'd like to do):

```
tuple = 'one', two'
function('add this')
```

I'd never imagine that `function` changed tha value of `tuple`. Anyway, it could be done with:

```
tuple = 'one', 'two'

def function(string):
    global tuple
    if new_string not in tuple:
        tuple = (new_string,) + tuple

function('add this')
```

Also something like this could be done:

```
tuple = 'one', two'
function(tuple, 'add this')
```

I'd say it's a little better because if I were to use your code having probelms I might guess that `function` does something to tuple.

And the code would be:

```
tuple = 'one', 'two'

def function(old_tuple, string):
    global tuple
    if new_string not in old_tuple:
        tuple = (new_string,) + old_tuple

function(tuple, 'add this')
```

**At the end I'd say that what you're doing right now is clear and more simple, I wouldn't change it.**

Comment: The last code block you have there is what I would like, however I would also like the function to be in a separate file than the tuple and the calling of the function. When I do what you have there, it does change the tuple in the file with the function, but it does not keep the edited version after calling the function, in the file with the tuple, when called from the tuple file.

Comment: Actually I think you are right, it is better what I have. More clear. I am still curious if the other way is possible though.

Comment: @saul.shanabrook: Yes, is way more clear, unless you're really forced to use global one should pass parameters as parameters :) Out of curiosity I'd have to say that what you were trying to do using two files would have ended in a cyclic import hence an error.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
def function(new_string):
if new_string not in variable.tuple:
    variable.tuple = (new_string,) + variable.tuple
```

Comment: It works if they are in the same file. If they are not it doesn't. the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9000442/907060) explains it well.